Book title probably written 1970’s - young adult lit about a boy who dives into water and travel different place & maybe time - maybe an island
I realize this is vague. I am struggling remembering details. I do remember doing a book report on this book (I think when I was 12 or so), that’s why I think it was in the 1970’s, with a possibility of early 1980’s. I also, now while I’m writing, I think that this boy when he dives down and swims underwater and comes up on the “other”side, he is blue or the people on the other side are blue. I just can’t remember. The drawing part of my book report I just remember a boy on an island with a coconut tree and I think I colored him blue. I sure hope this sparks a remembrance in someone. Thanks to anyone and everyone in advance. AP

This isn't part of the "Time Traders" series by Andre Norton is it?. In one of them, Key out of Time the protagonist Ross Murdock (not a boy, but in his early 20's maybe) has to dive through a gate just off a tropical island to do the time travel and face off with the "Baldies" who dress in blue skin-tight suits. Lots of different covers at ISFDB

Hmmm. I don’t remember it being a series nor if there was a conflict/battle between worlds… but I am excited to find this book and read a little of it to see if this is the one! Thank you for the information. I’ll let you know what I find out!

Hello again bob1, I read a 47pg preview of Key Out Of Time, thank you for your idea, it was not the book however. That one was too advanced. I did just edited my original post, I read this one back when I was at the oldest 12 yrs old, and maybe even younger. Thanks though again for throwing out a thought!!

Good to know. Stick around, you might get some other suggestions.
